# I am trying to enter the values in a array by for loop but loop is taking only one value and than program is closed

Tags: c++, for-loop

I created an array of user-defined size and trying to enter the values but when `for-loop` is executed it is only taking one value

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int s;
    cin>>s;
    vector <int> arr;
    int input;
    for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
       {cin>>input;
        arr[i]=input;}
       for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
        cout<<" "<<arr[i];
}
```

my input

5

1 2

expected input

5

1 2 3 4 5

output

program crashed after entering the value `1`

expected output

1 2 3 4 5

Comment: `arr[i]=input;` invokes *undefined behavior* - you add new elements to a vector using `push_back`

Comment: Your `vector <int> arr;` doesn't provide storage for any element. Either you have to add elements with `arr.push_back(input);` or you have to provide storage beforehand using `std::vector<int> arr(s);`.